# How to read from 2 files

Tags: bash

I try to make a script to connect with MySQL.

Reading hosts from one file and the MySQL password from another file, but I have a problem.

When I try to execute the script it's returning me this error:

```
./do: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The code is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
INFO=$2
cat $FILE | while read HOST;
cat $INFO | while read INFO;do
DBS=`mysql -u root -p $INFO -h $HOST --connect_timeout=4 -Bse'show databases' | wc -l`
if [ "$DBS" -gt "0" ]; then
echo $HOST - mysql - $DBS >> log.sql
fi
sleep 0.1
done
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: @MichaelGardner same error, i've tryed

Comment: The error message surprises me somewhat, but you seem to have two whiles and only one do and done. That can't work.

Comment: You have 2 `while` statements, and only one set of `do`/`done`.

Comment: Can you describe, in high-level terms, what are you trying to do? There is more than one way to iterate over two files.

Comment: @MichaelGardner: Well, this is parse error. It happens before anything really gets executed.

Comment: well that error is done , i've cleared up.. but on while read INFO is not takeing $INFO on the secound like

Answer (score 0):

Salut Dragoș,

You can't use two while loops (even after you fix the syntax error) to read from two different files **at the same time**.

Instead, you can use *paste* to combine the two files first, then execute your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostnames="$1"
passwords="$2"

while IFS=$'\t' read host password; do
    dbs=$(mysql -u root -p "$password" -h "$host" --connect_timeout=4 -Bse'show databases' | wc -l)
    [ $dbs -gt 0 ] && echo "$host - mysql - $dbs" >> log.sql
done <<<"$(paste "$hostnames" "$passwords")"
```

This script will correctly handle filenames with spaces, as well as hostnames and passwords containing spaces.

Comment: Not entirely true, you can have `read` read from two different file descriptors.

Comment: @Adrian Frühwirth: True, you could do `while read ... && read ...`, but then you'd have to open the file descriptors explicitly before the `while` loop too, which seems cumbersome for this scenario. Or is there a quicker way to read from two different descriptors?